Dimensions with QAD
i would like to use QAD plugin to make polygons with dimensions in QGIS, i came across a problem (that's what i think it is).
When i set the text layer for dimension style i can't make it to align with the dimension line. I know that there is an option for that but that option is checked.
Can help me with this issue?


